# 2 IE8 behave differently

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am having a problem where 2 IE8 (with the same version number 8.0.6001.18702) behave differently in processing a webpage.
The misbehaving one is of course used by the client :) , and I just cannot reproduce it on my machine or on our test machine. It is all good on Firefox btw.

How can I narrow down what is causing this problem?

Thanks

Edit:
Clicking on a submit button obviously should submit a form, but on the client's IE, it just doesn't do that.

Comment: What's different about the behavior?

Comment: Clicking on a submit button obviously should submit a form, but on the client's IE, it just doesn't do that.

Comment: Did you check if compatibility mode is enabled on the client's IE?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page in question?

Comment: Your tags mention Javascript, is the form submitted using JS? May it be turned off?

Comment: @Andrew yes, tried with compatibility mode both on and off, and both didn't work.

Comment: @Matt I wish I can post the link, but you will need to login, and i just cannot give out the login details..

Comment: @deceze - no, if JS is turned off, the form cannot be submitted. I am using CakePHP framework with Prototype JS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested on other browsers than Firefox and IE? The default behavior of `button` and `input` buttons varies a bit from browser to browser (I think the standard used to be a bit vague about this or was easily misinterpreted).. What type of button is it? I think `<input type="submit">` tends to be more reliable across browsers..

BTW, If you've attached some JavaScript to the button it may be that's what causing the problems, too... IE has a very small yellow warning icon on the status indicationg script errors, but since IE is "somewhat quirky" you'll get used to it being there all the time and you might not notice a fatal error ;)

(IE8 supposedly removed a lot of nonstandard quirks and got more "standard compliant", but in my experience they've allso created a lot of really weird new quirks, unseen in any previous version...)

Comment: yes there are some JavaScript code attached to the submit button because I am using CakePHP framework.
I didn't notice there was any JavaScript Error displayed on IE..maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are differences with respect to add-ins (plugins), toolbars etc. 
E.g. Skype add-in inserts it's own formatting of phone numbers and a way to make a call by clicking on them.

Comment: that's why using extoff is useful […]

Answer (score 0):

You could ask him to execute ie8 with the command line argument `-extoff`.
If it's not fixing the problem, the compatibility mode is maybe triggered somehow.
Of course remember to check that you are not calling local files (that's obvious but who knows).

update: (just read the comments) is js enabled on his side too?